# Java - naming convention for can-do interface as opposed to can-be-done-to

Tags: java, interface, naming-conventions

In Java more often than not I have come across interfaces with the suffix `-able`, e.g. `serializable`, `iterable`, etc.  This suggests that the object that implements these interfaces has qualities such that certain actions can be done **to** it, e.g. the object can be serialized or can be iterated over.  What if I want to implement an interface that suggests that certain actions can be done **by** the object rather than **to** the object.

For example, it makes sense for a human to implement an interface along the lines of `CanDrive` but does not make sense for a human to implement the interface `Drivable`, as a human cannot be driven.  A car, conversely, should implement `Drivable` but certainly should not implement `CanDrive` because no car should ever drive itself.

The name `CanDrive` sounds remarkable ugly to me as an interface name.  Is there a suffix convention for naming an interface that suggests this kind of can-do relationship (as opposed to can-be-done-to)?

Comment: Obligatory: [Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html).

Comment: There is `Iterable`, and also there is `Iterator`. I think vehicles can be Drivable but human can be Driver.

Comment: and throwable is a class not an interface and instead of `CanDrive` is like a boolean condition, `Driver` would be fit better

Comment: Re: throwable -> thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End the name in `-or` or `-er` (depending on English spelling).

There are lots of examples even in the JDK of interfaces that *do* things:

- Executor
- Conparator
- DocumentHelper
- Tokenizer

Etc.

And in your example of `CanDrive`, you would use `Driver`.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to use [agent nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun) or noun phrases for classes and interfaces that do things to other objects:

```
Serializer
ClassLoader
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much of a naming convention. For instance the **done to** `iterable` interface is related to the **can-be-done-by** `iterator` interface. `Comparable` to `Comparator` etc. It seems to me that if there is such a naming "convention" you'd use `-or` instead of `-able`.